Same project same code compile at two different machines, but one of them couldn't link the correct libglut.so at a third remote machine
I have a C project running in Linux using OpenGL that's managed in git. Computer X and computer Y have the same version of the code pulled from git. We'd like to send the executable to a third-party machine, Z, for running.
However, only the executable built on X computer works; the one that built in the VM of the Y computer failed to run on machine Z. Console on machine Z showed - error while loading shared library: libglut.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Question: why do the same code and the same project setting yield different results?
I'm looking into the difference between the X machine and Y machine.
The first thing I tried was to look into the version of the OpenGL. ref:Terminal command to show OpenGL version?
X computer:
emilylin@linux:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
emilylin@linux:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ 

VM of Y computer:
emilylin@linux:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 21.2.6
emilylin@linux:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$

Question: why I cannot find the gl version by using this command on X computer?
Then, I looked into the executable linking path to see what I could find there.
X computer:
emilylin@T:~/git/riv_port_replay_v2/Debug$ ldd ./riv_port_replay_v2 
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdbc7fc000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007b317dbd7000)
libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007b317db50000)
libglut.so.3.12 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.12 (0x00007b317d747000)
libGLU.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007b317daf7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007b317d400000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007b317dcd3000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007b317d68f000)
libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007b317d65c000)
libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007b317d2c3000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007b317daee000)
libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007b317d649000)
libOpenGL.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0 (0x00007b317d61e000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007b317d000000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007b317d296000)
libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007b317cfd7000)
libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007b317d282000)
libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007b317dae4000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007b317d616000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007b317cfc1000)
libmd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0 (0x00007b317cfb2000)

VM of Y computer:
emilylin@linux:~/git/remote_connect/riv_port_replay_v2/Debug$ ldd ./riv_port_replay_v2
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc7974c000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f152923d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f15290ee000)
libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f1529066000)
libglut.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 (0x00007f1528e1d000)
libGLU.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f1528dab000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1528da1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1528bad000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1529556000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f1528af5000)
libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f1528ac1000)
libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f1528984000)
libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f1528972000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f152896b000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1528787000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f152876c000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1528766000)
libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f152873c000)
libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f1528727000)
libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f152871f000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f1528717000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f15286fd000)

Question: do libglut.so.3 and libglut.so.3.12 make a difference in the result? Further, I went to the /usr/lib to try to find the .so itself, but couldn't find it on the X computer! So why did it print /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.12 (0x00007b317d747000) when I couldn't find it in the /usr/lib folder? While in the VM of Y computer I found a shared library named libglut.so as expected.
Update: I also gave the same command to machine Z. It has two executables that are built from machine X and machine Y. One of them has problem linking the libglut.so. console screenshot on machine Z running ldd Any idea on what caused this to happen?

You've not provided the obvious starting point, which is what Ubuntu product/release you're using.  I see different solutions/problems based on those unstated details.

Is it possible that machine Y was upgraded from 22.04 and had the older freeglut3 package installed?

Hi @guiverc, machine X is using Ubuntu 24.04; VM of machine Y is using Ubuntu 20.04; machine Z is using Ubuntu 24.04. Do you think it's caused by the differences between the OS?

Hi @steeldriver, Both X and Y have been in their Ubuntu 24.04 and 20.04 from the start. I wonder if upgrading the VM of machine Y to 24.04 will fix this though (or just create a new VM to test).

I forget what I looked at or saw yesterday (at a different location & on different box to now too), but I picked a package that matched message(s) on your screen & did a rmadison or other like query & it showed different versions between releases that could explain difference.. but you'd not provided release details... thus my comment. Yes I do think it could cause the difference, software changes over time & release gives us an easy clue on stack within it, but sorry I can't recall what package I did my enquiry on, and have little desire to explore again sorry.

Hi @guiverc, I tried to set up another VM running Ubuntu 24.04 to compile the program, and... it works! It works perfectly on machine Z. So it's caused by the OS!

Hey @guiverc, yes, correct! I solved this by adding another VM running 24.04 at machine Y. It turns out that the program compiled by Ubuntu 24.04 works fine!


Question: do libglut.so.3 and libglut.so.3.12 make a difference in the result?

Yes they do. Programs that are dynamically linked are not guaranteed to be portable across different versions of Ubuntu.
In particular, when your program is built on Machine Y (Ubuntu 20.04, amd64 architecture), the linker ld will resolve the library directive -lglut as /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3, which is a symbolic link to major.minor version /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0 provided by the freeglut3 package. The library major version libglut.so.3 gets "baked in" to the executable program.
In Ubuntu 24.04, the GLUT runtime library is provided by the libglut3.12 package, which only provides /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.12, as a symbolic link to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.12.0 - so the dynamic linker fails to resolve libglut.so.3.
This may just be a packaging oversight - it's possible that the newer library is actually ABI-compatible with the older one, and creating a symbolic link to libglut.so.3.12 named libglut.so.3 on the target Ubuntu 24.04 machine may allow your 20.04-built executable to run there (although I wouldn't recommend that as a solution).
See also How do SO (shared object) numbers work?
